# Excel VBA - Ignore continuous blank lines while save as a file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am having some content in `Sheet1` and I am doing some manipulations and writing them in `Sheet2`.

The objective is to write the `Sheet2` into a `.txt` file. The range is always going to be `A1:A2320` from `Sheet2`. So I loop and print them in the output file.

The problem I face is post manipulation there are a set of blank lines getting into the output file and it is always having 2321 lines (This is expected as per my code). I need to remove all subsequent blank lines in the range `A1:A2320` before printing, only if there is more than one continuous blank.

For Example if this is the sheet Temp after manipulation

```
A
B

C

D


E

.
```

This should be written as

```
A
B

C

D
E
.
```

This is what I made so far

```
Private Sub Make_Click()

Dim numFields As Integer
Dim numRows As Integer
Dim curField As Integer
Dim curRow As Integer
Dim tmpText As String
Dim outputFile As Variant

numFields = 1
numRows = 2320
curField = 1
curRow = 1

outputFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path _
            & "\", filefilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
            Title:="Output file name (will overwrite)")
If outputFile = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo failed
Open outputFile For Output As #1

For curRow = 1 To numRows
  For curField = 1 To numFields
    tmpText = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(curRow, curField).Value
    Print #1, tmpText;
    If curField < numFields Then
      Print #1, vbTab;
    End If
  Next curField
  Print #1, vbLf;
Next curRow
Close #1

MsgBox "File " & outputFile & " written. " & numFields & " fields, " & numRows & " rows."

Exit Sub

failed:
On Error Resume Next
Close #1
MsgBox "Couldn't create/overwrite file."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only dealing with one column of data, then checking for blanks is trivial. And if you are always only dealing with column A, why are you stepping through columns? You could use a counter to keep track of how many blank lines you have in a row...

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
...
For curRow = 1 To numRows
    tmpText = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Cells(curRow, 1).Value
    If Len(tmpText) > 0 Then
        If counter = 1 Then
            Print #1, vbLf
        End If
        Print #1, tmpText
        Print #1, vbLf
        counter = 0
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next curRow
```

We just delay printing the single blank line until we find the next non-blank. Now if you want to keep a single blank when it occurs on the last row, you will need to stick an if statement on the end of this code.